# InfoPath Forms Services is not turned on

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

I installed MOSS 2k7 Enterprise and now, I would like to use the Workflow feature. 
The problem is that :

1. When I start any workflow, I have got the error "InfoPath Forms Services is not turned on"
2. In Central Administrator -> Application Management -> InfoPath Forms Services, I tried to : (a)"Manageform templates" (b) "configure InfoPath Forms Services", "Upload form templates", but I always receive the same error "InfoPath Forms Services is not turned on"
3. I tried to create an InfoPath file and publish in the SharePoint site but it does not work

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Linh Linh: If you have more information for the question please edit it rather than add a new answer (because what you've added is not an answer). Also this is not a programming question and may be better answered at http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Go to the site collection's site setting where you want to enable this service.select Site Collection Features and then activate Infopath form services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

1. Go to Central Administration > Operations > Enable Features on existing sites
2. Tick the check box "Enable all sites..."